# Preventing axios multiple calls

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I use axios in my VueJS app. For the moment, in every component, I use a variable in every component to check is the user has already clicked on the button before launching the axios call.
It leads to a lot of repetitive code, so I thought about wrapping my axios calls into a function "uniqueAxios", like this:

```
const urlsAPI = [];
const uniqueAxios = async (method, url, data) => {
  if (urlsAPI.includes(url)) {
    console.log('Already called!!');
    Promise.reject(new Error('Already called'));
  } else {
    urlsAPI.push(url);
    await axios[method](url, data)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log('OK');
        console.log(res);
        return Promise.resolve(res);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log('KO');
        console.log(e);
        return Promise.reject(e);
      });
  }
};
```

But when I use this function in my component, like this:

```
await uniqueAxios(
          'post',
          `${process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL}/XXX`,
        )
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
```

The console throws an error: `TypeError: res is undefined`. The API is contacted, though. It's just that I can't handle the `then` and the `catch` I had previously when I used axios directly.

I'm sure the wrapping `uniqueAxios` function is not correct.
Does anybody know how I should handle this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code

```
const urlsAPI = [];

const uniqueAxios = async (method, url, data) => {
  if (urlsAPI.includes(url)) {
    console.log('Already called!!');
    Promise.reject(new Error('Already called'));
  } else {
    urlsAPI.push(url);
    await axios[method](url, data)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log('OK');
        console.log(res);
        return Promise.resolve(res);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log('KO');
        console.log(e);
        return Promise.reject(e);
      });
  }
};
```

All `async` functions return a promise, even something like:

```
async function three() {
  return 3;
}
```

or this

```
async function belch() {
  throw new Error("Belch!");
}
```

which will resolve or reject depending on whether or not an error was thrown.

Since you're not explicitly returning a value, the return value is a Promise that resolves as `undefined` (unless an error is thrown, in which case it rejects).

Your code would be cleaner (and work!) if you merely said something like this:

```
const inFlightUrls = new Set();

const uniqueAxios = async (method, url, data) => {

  const inflight = inFlightUrls.has(url);
  if (inFlight) {
    throw new Error('Already called');
  }

  inFlightUrls.add(url);

  const res = axios[method](url, data)
              .finally( () => inflightUrls.delete(url) ) ;

  return res ;
};
```

The above function returns a promise that either resolves with the Axios response object, or rejects with an error (either from Axios or thrown by you).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. What do you think of the answer I posted after having read Raphael's one? I'd like your expertise on it. It works for me in my app but I may have written improper code.

Comment: That probably works, but it's awfully complicated. The whole point of `async`/`await` is that it's syntactic sugar that gets rid of all the callbacks and gives you more straightforward procedural code.

Comment: I've tried your answer, it works like a charm and the `Set` is a really good idea... I voted it instead of mine, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT: it works but the answer I selected is far better]

Actually I found a solution:

```
let urlsAPI = [];
const uniqueAxios = async (method, url, data) => {
  if (urlsAPI.includes(url)) {
    throw new Error('Axios already called');
  }
  urlsAPI.push(url);
  const t = {
    type: 0,
    content: null,
  };
  await axios[method](url, data)
    .then((res) => {
      t.content = res;
      t.type = 1;
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      t.content = e;
    })
    .finally(() => {
      urlsAPI = urlsAPI.filter((u) => u !== url);
    });
  if (t.type) {
    return t.content;
  }
  throw t.content;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problem, the first is you return nothing in your function.

```js
const uniqueAxios = async (method, url, data) => {
  if (urlsAPI.includes(url)) {
    console.log('Already called!!');
    Promise.reject(new Error('Already called'));
  } else {
    urlsAPI.push(url);
    return await axios[method](url, data) // You need to return the axios
      .then((res) => {
        console.log('OK');
        console.log(res);
        return Promise.resolve(res); // This line return inside the promise axios not the function
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log('KO');
        console.log(e);
        return Promise.reject(e);
      });
  }
};
```

Second things is you await and do a then for nothing on nothing.
Now with this change you can await your function like this and log a response.

```js
const response = await uniqueAxios(
  'post',
  `${process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL}/XXX`,
  )
console.log(response)
```

Comment: Thanks Raphael, I managed to solve my problem and posted an answer. You can review it if you want.

Comment: Yes you do the same as the second block. It's the best, save the response inside a const and do something with ;)
But understand for maybe other time, when your return a bloc like ir the `then` this return inside the promise and not the initial block statement (same with map, filter ....).